# How can I know with confidence that a user hasn't changed a textbox value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I'm working on Wordpress and want to send the user id to the server for process with AJAX. So I store this value (`user_id`) in an hidden input textbox, and every time I read this value, pass it to jQuery and send to server by AJAX. The problem is that users can change this value (by inspecting the page). The below code is one of my attempts:

```
<input hidden="true" type="text" id="userid" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id() ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
   $( document ).ready( function(){     
      var previousValue = $("#userid").val();
      $("#userid").keyup(function(e){
      var currentValue = $(this).val();
      if(currentValue != previousValue){
         $('#userid').val(previousValue);
      }
     });
    }
</script>
```

But apparently it can't be executed when the user inspects the page (via Chrome, Firefox or anything else) and changes the value. How can I authenticate a user id?

Comment: You can't, it's that simple, the value of an input can always be changed by the user, and someone can easily send an ajax request to your server without even using a browser, that contains whatever data they choose to send, there's no security in that solution.

Comment: Why is that a problem? User owns the browser. You can't assume that anything that comes from the client is legit. You need to perform this check on the server side.

Comment: Store the `userid` in the session! Its safe there. In fact it might already be in the session

Comment: A session is just a cookie with an ID that identifies the user, basically the same thing, albeit a little harder to hijack.

Comment: This is actually simple:  If all you want to do is get the current user id for your ajax work, then simply use `get_current_user_id()` *in your AJAX function*.  It will return the correct, current user ID.

Comment: Security is the most important aspect in my work! and thus i need it. You said there is no security in this solution. How can i provide security? thanks for your comment @adeneo

Comment: _"So i store this value (user_id) in an hidden input textbox, and every time i read this value, pass it to jQuery and send to server by Ajax. "_ Is user id different for each load of page ? How does `get_current_user_id()` determine which user is viewing page ?, and which user id to embed in `html` ? Why is user `id` embedded in `html` ?

Comment: There's no way to guarantee security for this, and it's not really needed either, the user has control over the browser, and anything you send to that browser is accessible by the user, period. Also, anyone can send anything to your server, you have to make sure someone just can't guess a random user id and get access to users data etc. Finally, `get_current_user` is available serverside, you don't have to output it clientside just to send it to a server that already has access to that data to begin with.

Comment: No it isn't. but users can change the user id. I embedded in html because i want it pass to jQuery and send to server by ajax. You know, I can't use php inside of script tag. @guest271314

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem here. When you make an AJAX call, you make it to some PHP page, right? That PHP script should just pull the user id from the server, instead of relying on it to be sent from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done. You can never guarantee anything about what happens on the client. All the ways to prevent someone tampering with the user ID would rely on the browser somehoe enforcing it, but the client could run *any piece of software on their machine*. Therefore all security arrangement must rest on the assumption that any data sent by the client can not be trusted.

I guess that what you are trying to do is to identify a user. That can actually be achieved by using [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). Store the user id in the PHP session variable instead. If you want, you can pass it to the client, but don't rely on that to enforce any authentication. In other words, don't have the client pass it back to the server.

So, what does this practically mean for you? Wordpress already uses PHP sessions to keep track of the user. When you do an AJAX call, I asume it goes to some PHP page. That PHP script should just get the user id from Wordpress (i.e. the server) using [`get_current_user_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id), instead of having it sent from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Use a hashing technique and hash your userid.
2. Send original userid and hash value to the client system (hidden field can be an option).
3. Send back userid and hash value through ajax from client to server.
4. Hash userid once again using same hashing technique in the server.
5. If pervious hash value match with recent hash value, then nothing tampered.

Comment: What does this accomplish, that cant just be done using session variables without manually hasing things?

Comment: If data is tampered, through cryptographic hashing it can be identified .

Comment: Yes. But why develop your own custom solution when you can just set a session variable, like `$_SESSION["user_id"] = user_id;`? If you for some reason really want to send the value to the client and back to see if has been modified, just compare it to the session variable. I think that is easier to implement and probably more secure since it does not rely on a custom solution.

Comment: Yes, you can but something called session hijacking and it's a security threat if not implemented properly. Also session may not be always desirable to a load balancer system.

Comment: Wordpress comes with good security out of the box. There is really no reason for anyone who is not a security expert (I asume OP is not) to roll their own solutions here.